Meaning of 但願今生能多交朋友，共此有情天地。
但願今生能多交朋友，共此有情天地。
I'm guessing this sentence means something like "Hope in this life to make more friends, together have feeling through the earth and sky".
As you can see its a very rudimentary translation and frankly I have no idea what it means. I probably translated it wrong anyway.
Is 今生 this life or my life? Why not use 這生?
共此 I think means "together here"?
有情天地 literally says "deep emotion in earth and sky". What does this even mean?
Thanks for the help.

People tend to interpret 天地 literally as "Sky and Earth" This phrase does not mean the "Sky and Earth" per se, but the area, the space bounded by these two extreme physical limits within which humans or human society is enclosed, i.e., the World where humans live. When humans look at his "World" he sees above it the sky, (heaven, 天), and below him the earth, (地) Just like the phrase "within four walls" means, not just the "four walls", but an enclosed space or area that is typically indoors, such as a living room or an office. Thus, "within four walls" means the space within the four walls.

"今生" = this life. "今" means the same as in "今年".
Yes, you can use "這(ㄧ)生", but it is not as poetic as "今生" or "此生".
"共此" is abbreviated from "共同享此XX" - "together to enjoy/share this XX".
"有情天地" - a world full of/filled with affection.

"情" - affection.

"天地"(heaven and earth) indirectly means "the world (世間)".


"但願今生能多交朋友，共此有情天地。" - Wish (I) be able to make plenty of friends in this life/my lifetime, together (with my dear friends) to enjoy/share this affection-filled world.

但願 - just wish
今生 - current life
能 - can
多交朋友- make more friends
共 - share
此 - this
有情 - loving
天地 - heaven and earth (world)

但願今生能多交朋友，共此有情天地。


Just wish to make more friends in my current life, and share this loving world with them

共 is acting as a verb 共享 (share) here
